# 'Read' collection logic in a Backbone sync override

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

In [the O'Reilly 'Developing backbone.js applications'](http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/#backbones-sync-api) example for overriding Backbone.sync, there is the following logic to run example `findAll()` vs `find()` methods:

```
case 'read':
  if (model.attributes[model.idAttribute]) {
    return MyAPI.find(model, success, error);
  } else {
    return MyAPI.findAll(model, success, error);
  }
}
```

Running `fetch()` on a `Collection` causes the following error: `model.idAttribute is undefined`

That's because the parameter `model` contains a collection when `myCollection.fetch()` is called. So it doesn't contain `idAttribute`.

It seems to me that simply testing for the existence of `model.idAttribute` would suffice to differentiate between a `Model` and a `Collection`, in order to switch between `find()` and `findAll()`.

Am I missing something else here? This is an authoritative resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code fix should probably be something like

```
case 'read':
if (model.idAttribute) {
    if (model.attributes[model.idAttribute]) {
        return MyAPI.find(model, success, error);
    }
} else {
    return MyAPI.findAll(model, success, error);
}
```

You need to test for both, because the model might define which attribute is it's id with the `idAttribute` value, but the actual id value might not be present. In other words, if the model instance you receive is

```
{
    idAttribute: "myId",
    name: "test"
}
```

You can't call your `find` method, because you have to id value to use in your query (i.e. `myModel.get("myId")` wont return anything).

Comment: Although, you could handle that in find()

Answer (score 1):

You can try `instanceof` :

```
case 'read':
  if (model instanceof Backbone.Model && model.idAttribute) {
    return MyAPI.find(model, success, error);
  } else if (model instanceof Backbone.Collection) {
    return MyAPI.findAll(model, success, error);
  } else {
    // the model have no idAttribute
  }
}
```

Comment: Your example doesn't use instanceof?

Comment: @robC I don't know what happened but the last edits of my answer were lost :)

Comment: Lol thanks I find that clearer. But if the idAttribute test is duck typing, it's kind of redundant in your example.

Comment: I added it just in case you want to deal with this case.